# Windows 7 bug after clean install

Tags: windows-7

I've just installed Windows 7 Ultimate Build 7600 and my internet connection still isn't working after I formatted the drive. I set it up, username and password and it's saying:

"Error 651: The modem (or other connecting device) has reported an error.

I've read that this is a bug and that I need the file: rapppoe.sys d from a working Vista system. I tried this before the clean install, but not sure if that was a good file.

Any suggestions ? If someone is kind enough to upload the rapppoe.sys file found in C:\Windows\system32\drivers. A direct link because I'm on my phone or e-mail it to x@yahoo.com

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Might want to take your email out of normal typeface so a searcher doesn't find it. Also, just use the CD that came with your computer and re-install drivers.

Comment: I would post it, but I need web-space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://www.windowsreference.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/raspppoe.zip) for a vista rapppoe.sys.
Note 1: Not my file, so I can't guarantee it.
Note 2: The rapppoe.sys method is not guaranteed to work.